# If player answers Y, game gets played again but if no or anything else it ends or provides an error message

Tags: java

I created a blackjack game that works perfectly except for the part where the user is asked if they want to play again. At this point, if anything except No is typed in that section, gameplay continues. So even if someone put a number in there, the game will start again. If they put in No or N, the game exits and tells them thank you for playing. I want it to be more specific and make them choose either a Y or a N and any other value will tell them that they need to answer with a Y or a N.

```
public class play {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = "";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    do {
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again ([Y] / [N])?");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(userInput);
    } while (userInput.equals("Y") || userInput.equals(""));
       //     System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want it to be more specific and make them choose either a Y or a N and any other value will tell them that they need to answer with a Y or a N."*

Use a *[Boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html)* value to determine whether the loop should be exited or not.
And, set it's value from within the loop.

Use the *Boolean* object, also, as opposed to a *boolean* primitive.
This way, you can use a *null* value for invalid entries.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean exit = null;
    do {
        System.out.print("Do you want to play again ([Y] / n)?");
        userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(userInput);
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            exit = false;
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            exit = true;
        } else {
            exit = null;
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
        }
    } while (exit == null || !exit);
    //     System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Do you want to play again ([Y] / n)?abc
abc
Invalid entry, try again.
Do you want to play again ([Y] / n)?y
y
Do you want to play again ([Y] / n)?n
n
```

Comment: I had to add a import java.util.Scanner then I get these errors: C:\Users\nhicks\Desktop\Mini-Project #2_NHicks_EN.605.201.81>javac Blackjack.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."
Blackjack.java:932: error: illegal start of type
import java.util.Scanner;
^
Blackjack.java:932: error: <identifier> expected
import java.util.Scanner;
                        ^
2 errors

Comment: :938: error: cannot find symbol
        userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
 939: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(userInput);
:940: error: cannot find symbol
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
940: error: cannot find symbol
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
  942: error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

Comment: @Nicole, make sure the _import_ statements are at the top of the file, and not in the middle.

Comment: 935 error: cannot find symbol
        userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
935 error: cannot find symbol
        userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
936 error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(userInput);
937 error: cannot find symbol
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
937 error: cannot find symbol
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
939 error: cannot find symbol
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

Comment: What do I need to do to fix these errors?

Comment: It looks like it can't locate the _userInput_ variable.  Is it still within the code?  I only provided the _main_ method.

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in a method, you can use this code in the main method ->

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Play {  
    static Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String userInput = "";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        requestPlayAgain();
    }
    public static void requestPlayAgain() {
        boolean incorrectInput; // boolean containing if the input isn't "yes" or "no" / "y" or "n"
        String lowerCaseUserInput;
        do {
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again ([Y] / [N])?");
            userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
            lowerCaseUserInput = userInput.toLowerCase(); // converts userInput into lower case
            incorrectInput = !(
                    lowerCaseUserInput.equals("y")
                    || lowerCaseUserInput.equals("n") 
                    || lowerCaseUserInput.equals("yes")
                    || lowerCaseUserInput.equals("no")
                    ); //checks whether the value is equal to "yes" or "no" / "y" or "n"
            
            if(incorrectInput) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect reply '"+userInput+"', use [Y] / [N] or [Yes] / [No]"); //Sends an error message requesting the user to use "yes" or "no"/"y" or "n"
            }
        } while (incorrectInput);
        switch(lowerCaseUserInput) { //checks what the value is
        case "y", "yes": /*   code/method to restart the game   */ break;
        case "n", "no": System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); System.exit(0); break; //System.exit(0) exits the program with exit code 0
        }
    }
}
```

The switch statement can also be swapped by a if statement like so ->

```
    if(lowerCaseUserInput.equals("y") || lowerCaseUserInput.equals("yes")) {
            /*   code/method to restart the game   */
    }
    else if(lowerCaseUserInput.equals("n") || lowerCaseUserInput.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); System.exit(0);
    }
```

A quick summary of what this code does :-

1. converts `userInput` into smaller case for flexibility which allows input like "yEs". You could use `userInput.equalsIgnoreCase()` too.
2. checks whether userInput is equal to "yes" or "no" / "y" or "n"
3. if `userInput` is not "yes"..., sends an error message requesting the user to use "yes"...
4. if `userInput` is "yes"..., checks if it is "yes" or "no"
5. if it is yes it continues the game, else it says "Thank you for playing" and exits the game

if done correctly you can end up with your output looking like this ->

```
Do you want to play again ([Y] / [N])?a
Incorrect reply 'a', use [Y] / [N] or [Yes] / [No]
Do you want to play again ([Y] / [N])?b
Incorrect reply 'b', use [Y] / [N] or [Yes] / [No]
Do you want to play again ([Y] / [N])?n
Thank you for playing!
```

A small mistake I noticed while checking the code was naming the class, which I believe was a typo, but preferably class names have each word's first letter capitalized according to [Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Comment: 933: error: illegal start of type
  import java.util.Scanner;
  ^
933: error: <identifier> expected
  import java.util.Scanner;
                          ^
Blackjack.java:936: error: illegal start of expression
public class Play {
^
962: error: : expected
        case "y", "yes": /*   code/method to restart the game   */ break;
                ^
Blackjack.java:963: error: : expected
        case "n", "no": System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); System.exit(1); break; //System.exit(1) exits the program with exit code 1
                ^

Comment: I got these errors, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37279307/21252090t), and [this](https://rollbar.com/blog/how-to-fix-illegal-start-of-expression-in-java/#:~:text=As%20its%20name%20implies%2C%20the,%2C%20i.e.%2C%20free%20of%20errors.). Incase you are using Eclipse, remove all your imports and press the hotkey -> ctrl+shift+o, it will automatically import what's needed

Comment: I got these errors from the code above: Blackjack.java:934: error: illegal start of type
import java.util.Scanner;
^
Blackjack.java:934: error: <identifier> expected
import java.util.Scanner;
                        ^
962: error: : expected
        case "y", "yes": /*   code/method to restart the game   */ break;
                ^
963: error: : expected
        case "n", "no": System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); System.exit(0); break; //System.exit(0) exits the program with exit code 0
                ^
Blackjack.java:966: error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: I have no idea why you get this error, the code works perfectly fine for me and probably for most other users. Instead of copying all the code given in the answer, try copying the `requestPlayAgain` method into your class, then execute the method where needed.

Comment: That looks better, it has only 2 errors: Blackjack.java:951: error: : expected
        case "y", "yes": /*   code/method to restart the game   */ break;
                ^
Blackjack.java:952: error: : expected
        case "n", "no": System.out.println("Thank you for playing!"); System.exit(0); break; //System.exit(0) exits the program with exit code 0
                ^
2 errors

C:\Users\nhick

Comment: Maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45199126/21252090) or remove the `switch(lowerCaseUserInput)...` statement completely and paste the if statement that I have provided with the answer.